# @media My media query doesn't work when I use 888px or less

Tags: css, media

My media query isn't working properly when I use it with some width. For example, if I use it with 1000px, everything is ok, but with 888px, isn't working. How can I fix it?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 888px) {
    #articles article {
        width: 40%;
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

Images here:

[image: Normal web site desing]

[image: When I use 1000px max-width]

[image: When I use THE SAME CODE but with 888px max-width]

Just in case, I added this in my HTML

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" user-scalable="no">
```

And now it's working, but I don't know really well why this happened

Thanks :)

Comment: Is the width of the screen definitely lower than 888px?

Comment: 700px or even just 100px and nothing happens if I delete the HTML viewport

Comment: Oh that's strange. Are there any CSS rules below 888px only that might conflict with `#articles article`?

Comment: you might have zoomed in/out of the browser

Comment: My screen was 100% zoomed. @AkberIqbal

Comment: @Daniel_Knights nope. In fact, I was just learning responsive desing and use all the website with %, it was the first media query rule

Comment: I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work in that case

Answer (score 0):

Your browser's max-width is larger without the viewport metatag because it is set to zoom-out the page.